Render comboboxes into a jtable
I tried to create a Jtable with comboboxes in one column. Therefore I use my own renderer for that special column. But after opening my table the column is filled with text „java.swingx….“. As soon as I resize my gui, the boxes get displayed correctly. How can I get them without resizing the gui?
public class MyWlWertRenderder extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
JComboBox combo;

public MyWlWertRenderder(JComboBox combobox)
{
    combo = new JComboBox();
    for (int i=0; i<combobox.getItemCount(); i++)
    {
        combo.addItem(combobox.getItemAt(i));
    }
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                               boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (value instanceof WlWert) {
        WlWert wert = (WlWert) value;
        setText(wert.getLangform());
    }

    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        setBackground(table.getSelectionForeground());
    }

    combo.setSelectedItem(value);

    return combo;
}

}
'''

I found the solution:
revalidate and repaint did the trick
